# NotNull extension method with dynamic objects for avoiding ternary operator

Tags: c#

I built this extension method:

```
public static class NotNullExtensionMethod
{
    public static Tresult NotNull<Tin, Tresult>
        (this Tin a, Func<Tin, Tresult> whenNotNull)
    {
        return a != null ? whenNotNull(a) : default(Tresult);
    }
}
```

Which lets me output if an object is not null, in this way:

```
foo.OptionalField.NotNull(r => r.SomeStringField);
```

If `OptionalField` is null, it will output a null string. If not, it will output the string itself.

The whole idea is to avoid ternary operator:

```
foo.OptionalField == null ? "" : foo.OptionalField.SomeStringField;
```

This works only with typified objects and I need something similar to work with dynamic objects. For example, lets say I have this dynamic object:

```
dynamic foo = new 
{
    optionalField = someCondition ? null : new 
    {
        someStringField = "blah"
    }
}
```

I'd love to use my `NotNull` extension method, like this:

```
foo.NotNull(r => r.optionalField)
```

But I know it is not possible to use extension methods with dynamics... **so is there any workaround in which I can avoid doing ternary operator**?

```
foo.optionalField == null ? "" : foo.optionalField.someStringField;
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the null coalescing (??) and/or null conditional (?.) operators. For example `foo.OptionalField?.SomeStringField ?? ""`?

Comment: Because of my C# version. I could update my C# version but... does it work with dynamic? eg.  `someDynamicObject?.someDynamicField?.foo`

Comment: AFAIK it would. Although usually the issue with dynamic objects is not knowing whether a member exists (which will cause a binding exception), but your extension method doesn't handle that anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Do you particularly need it to be an extension method? You could use a `using static` directive to bring in a static method so you could call:

```
var result = NotNull(foo, r => r.optionalField);
```

Maybe not quite as nice, but I suspect it's as nice as you'll get.

As noted in comments, the null conditional `?.` and null coalescing `??` operators may also be helpful.